# How to expand conformal normal ordering / operator product expansion?

Tags: operators, string-theory, conformal-field-theory

I'm working with Polchinski and my question is related to chapter 2 of his book *String Theory, Volume 1: Introduction to the Bosonic String*.

## What I believe to understand

An operator product expansion (OPE) yields something of the following form:
$$
T(z)A(0,0)=\dotso+\frac{h}{z^2}A(0,0)=\frac{1}{z}\partial A(0,0)+\dotso,\tag{2.4.14}
$$
with $h$ the *weight*. More precisely, $T(z)$ is defined as
$$
T(z)=\frac{-1}{\alpha^\prime}\colon\partial X^\mu\partial X_\mu\colon
\tag{2.4.4}$$
Now, a conformal normal ordering can be written as follows:
$$
\colon\mathcal{F}\colon=\exp\left(\frac{\alpha^\prime}{4}\int\!\mathrm{d}^2z_1\mathrm{d}^2z_2\log|z_{12}|^2\frac{\delta}{\delta X^\mu\left(z_1,z^*_1\right)}\frac{\delta}{\delta X_\mu\left(z_2,z^*_2\right)}\right)\mathcal{F}\tag{2.2.7}
$$

## What I don't understand

How is the OPE expanded? Say, $F=X^\nu$, then
$$
T(z)X^\nu(0,0)=\frac{-1}{\alpha^\prime}\colon\partial X^\mu\partial X_\mu\colon X^\nu(0,0),
$$
which, to leading order, should be equal to
$$
\frac{-1}{\alpha^\prime}\left(\partial X^\mu\partial X_\mu+\frac{\alpha^\prime}{4}\int\!\mathrm{d}^2z_1\mathrm{d}^2z_2\log|z_{12}|^2\frac{\delta}{\delta X^\mu\left(z_1,z^*_1\right)}\frac{\delta}{\delta X_\mu\left(z_2,z^*_2\right)}\partial X^\rho\partial X_\rho\right)X^\nu(0,0).
$$
How is this evaluated? In particular: What am I supposed to do with the $\frac{\delta}{\delta X^\mu\left(z_1,z^*_1\right)}\frac{\delta}{\delta X_\mu\left(z_2,z^*_2\right)}\partial X^\rho\partial X_\rho X^\nu(0,0)$ part?

Comment: Well these functional derivatives in particular are easy to evaluate because they just give delta functions. Indeed $$\dfrac{\delta X^\mu(z,\bar z)}{\delta X^\nu(w,\bar w)} = \delta^\mu_\nu \delta^{(2)}(z,w)$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Why is $\frac{\delta X^\mu}{\delta X^\nu}=\frac{\delta \partial X^\mu}{\delta X^\nu}$? What happens with the partial derivative here?

Comment: It simply isn't. The partials with respect to $z$ and $\bar z$ commute with the functional derivatives and they hit the delta function.

Comment: Thank you again, for replying. How is the $\frac{\delta}{\delta X^\mu\left(z_1,z^*_1\right)}\frac{\delta}{\delta X^\mu\left(z_2,z^*_2\right)}\partial X^\rho\partial X_\rho$ to be understood? Is it a $\frac{\delta\partial X^\rho\left(z_1,z^*_1\right)}{\delta X^\mu\left(z_1,z^*_1\right)}\frac{\delta\partial X_\rho\left(z_2,z^*_2\right)}{\delta X^\mu\left(z_2,z^*_2\right)}$ or should it expand into all 4 terms of possible derivations?

Comment: You should use the Liebnitz rule (functional derivatives are derivatives, after all). In that case you have for example $$\frac{\delta}{\delta X^\mu\left(z_2,z^*_2\right)}\partial X^\rho(z,\bar z)\partial X_\rho(z,\bar z) = \frac{\delta[\partial X^\rho(z,\bar z)]}{\delta X^\mu\left(z_2,z^*_2\right)}\partial X_\rho(z,\bar z)+\partial X^\rho(z,\bar z)\frac{\delta[\partial X_\rho(z,\bar z)]}{\delta X^\mu\left(z_2,z^*_2\right)}=2\frac{\delta[\partial X^\rho(z,\bar z)]}{\delta X^\mu\left(z_2,z^*_2\right)}\partial X_\rho(z,\bar z),$$ after recognizing the two terms are really the same.

Comment: Then you can commute the functional derivative with $\partial$ and evaluate this explicitly. After that you can take the other functional derivative.

Comment: Ah, yes, OK, so the functional derivatives act through. Should I then find $\frac{\delta}{\delta X^\mu(z)}\frac{\delta}{\delta X_\mu(\omega)}\partial X^\rho(z)\partial X_\rho(z)=\frac{\delta}{\delta X^\mu(z)}2\partial\frac{\delta X_\rho(z)}{\delta X^\mu(\omega)}\partial X^\rho(z)=\frac{\delta}{\delta X^\mu(z)}2\partial\delta^\rho_\mu\delta^2(z,\omega)\partial X^\rho(z)=\frac{\delta}{\delta X^\mu(z)}2\partial\partial X^\mu(\omega)=2\partial\partial D\delta(z,w)$ with D the dimension? As a next step: partial integration, where $\partial\partial\log |z-\omega|^2$ has to be evaluated.

Comment: Or should somewhere a $\partial_{z^*}$ occur, such that $\partial_{z^*}\partial_z\log |z-w|^2=2\pi\delta^2(z,\omega)$ can be used?